# Node.js lambda: how to import common layer utility lib in local development but also work in the cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-lambda-layers

I have a monorepo with a few functions in their own folder. I want to create a common layer with utility functions that I can `require/import` locally and also after deployment to the cloud. I want to add a `layers/` directory to do this, with the folder structure looking something like this:

```
  A
  |- node_modules/
  |- package.json
  |- index.js
  B
  |- node_modules/
  |- package.json
  |- index.js
  layers
    |- nodejs
      |- node_modules
      |- package.json
      |- util.js
```

I'm not set on the folder structure above and am OK with it changing.

Currently, I only have `A` and `B` with their own individual dependency layers (orchestrated using `terraform`), and they work great locally and deployed.

With the introduction of a common utility layer, the issue is that I can require/import locally but it wouldn't be the same in the cloud (`/opt/nodejs/*`), but if I change it up to work on the cloud, it won't work locally.

I am not using the `serverless` framework.